# using impilicits to make apply method easier to use

Tags: scala

I have the following setup:

```
trait Pr[I0<:ArgLike,I1<:ArgLike,+O]
  extends ((I0, I1) => O) {
  val name: String
  def apply(arg0,arg1):O
}

case class sum(arg0:Arg1,arg1: Arg2) extends Pr[Arg1,Arg2,t1]{
    val name = "adder"
    def apply(a0:Arg1,a1:Arg2) = t1(a0.toString + a1.toString + "output")
}
```

When I want to use `sum` I have to pass the arguments two times (one for case class, one for apply).

```
val b0 = Arg1("a0")
val b1 = Arg2()
val s = sum(b0,b1)(b0,b1)
```

How can I use implicits to make this easier and more intuitive, something like this:

```
val s = sum(b0,b1)
```

I want to have access to `arg0` and `arg1`, something like `sum.arg0` so I want them to be member of `Predicate`.

Comment: @Carl No, because Pr extending Function2 and it should implement apply method

Answer (score 1):

Implicits probably aren't necessary here, and they'll probably just complicate things.  For simplicity, let's say you're only working with `Ints`.  You can simply have an `apply` method on `Sum` that takes no parameters:

```
case class Sum(arg0: Int, arg1: Int) {
    val name = "adder"
    def apply() = arg0 + arg1
}
```

This allows you to compute the sum without needing to pass additional arguments, but you still have access to the arguments:

```
val mySum = Sum(1, 2)
mySum.arg0 //1
mySum() //3
```

You also don't have to use `apply` here.  You could name that method `get` or `value` or something similar, and then use `mySum.get` to compute the addition.

If you do insist on using implicits, you can add an implicit coversion from `Sum` to `Int` here.  Then the compiler can choose when to treat the instance as a `Sum`, and when to treat it as an `Int`:

```
case class Sum(arg0: Int, arg1: Int) {
    val name = "adder"
    def get = arg0 + arg1
}

object Sum {
    implicit def sumToInt(sum: Sum) = sum.get
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
val mySum = Sum(1, 2)
mySum.arg0 //1
4 + mySum //7
val myNewSum = Sum(mySum, 4) //Sum(3, 4)
myNewSum.get //7
myNewSum : Int //7
```

All of these techniques work just as well with generic parameters, I just removed them to underscore the relevant idioms.

The `Sum` case class really shouldn't extend `Function2`, since it doesn't require more arguments to generate a value. For example, what would you expect from `Sum(1, 2)(3, 4)`? An instantiated `Sum` instance more naturally extends `() => Int`, since that type requires no more arguments to generate a value.  If you need something that extends `Function2`, you might add a new object that generates `Sums`.  That object can naturally extend `Function2`:

```
object SumMaker extends ((Int, Int) => Sum) {
    def apply(arg0: Int, arg1: Int) = Sum(arg0, arg1)
}
```

And then you can do:

```
val mySum = SumMaker(1, 2)
mySum.arg0 //1
mySum : Int //3
val myFunc1 = SumMaker.apply _ //(Int, Int) => Sum
val myFunc: (Int, Int) => Int = SumMaker.apply
```

Comment: thanks, I really like to extend the Sum from Function2, that's the part that makes it a little bit complicated!

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to use implicits at all if case class sum is converted to an object.

```
object sum extends Pr[Arg1,Arg2,t1]{
    val name = "adder"
    def apply(a0:Arg1,a1:Arg2) = t1(a0.toString + a1.toString + "output")
}
```

After this it's possible to call sum as

```
val result = sum(b0,b1)
```

Case class `sum` should not have parameters unless they affect behavior of the `apply` function. 
As an example consider following:

```
trait Pr extends ((Int, Int) => Int) {
  val name: String
  def apply(arg0: Int,arg1: Int):Int
}

case class sumAndMultiply(mu: Int) extends Pr{
  val name = "adder"
  def apply(a0:Int,a1:Int) = (a0 + a1) * mu
}

sumAndMultiply(2)(1, 3)// result = 8
sumAndMultiply(3)(1, 3) // result = 12
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will use arg0 and arg1 in this case, because I need to have access that in my setup, something like `sum.arg0`